# how to change the style dynamically when using Android WebView to load a xml with css?

Tags: android, css, xml, webview

I use `webView.loadUrl("...");` to load the xml file, then try to use `webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.bgColor='red';");`  to change the style, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this to get this to work:

```
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:function changeBkgd() {"
                  + "    document.bgColor='red';"
                  + "}"
                  + " changeBkgd();");
```

i.e. define it in a function then call the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, though it doesn't work for me !  I doubt that I make mistakes elsewhere.